# Putting Dart Enum in Class or Package Export File

Tags: oop, dart, enums, structure

I am debating whether to put an enum (that will be referenced in multiple classes and files within my `src` folder) inside of one of the files in my `src` directory or within the export file that sits under the lib folder. I want to expose the enum, but I also do not want the user to import files besides the entrance file. Would it make sense to put the enum inside the entrance file in this case? My directory structure looks like this:

```
lib/
  entrance.dart <- Would here be ok?
  src/
     packages and files <- Or Does it have to be here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either.

If you declare the enum in a file under `src/`, say `src/enum.dart`, you can then export it from the `entrance.dart` using `export "src/enum.dart";`. Other users of the enum in `src/` just need to `import "enum.dart";`.

if you declare the enum in `entrance.dart`, you don't have to bother with exporting it, but all files in `src/` which uses the enum needs to `import "../entrance.dart";` (maybe with a `show` clause to avoid all the other things that are exported).

I'd personally go for the former approach, but either can work.

Comment: I did not even consider putting it in a separate file, but that would be helpful in case I need other classes or types to be accessed, thanks!